ExecutorService did not return finished Threads back to pool?
i have created an async Task-Thread which creates inside 8-Worker-Threads for long running jobs. Lets say i have 8 long running jobs, all works fine. All 8 Worker-Jobs complete in for example 10seconds. The Problem is now, if i set the FixedThreadPoolSize to 7 (One Thread less than my amount of Jobs) and i get again my 8 Jobs. It took not round about 10 seconds, it took nearly 70seconds. But why is this so? It looks like there are no more threads available from the pool. But the 7 Threads before are done. And for the last Thread he took 60seconds.
My TaskThread looks like this:
 private final ExecutorService executorService;
 private final OpenAiService openAiService;
 private final List<String> workerJobs;

 public TaskThread(List<String> workerJobs,OpenAiService openAiService;) {
    this.workerJobs = workerJobs;
this.openAiService = openAiService;
    this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7, Thread.ofVirtual().name("Thread-", 1).factory());
  }


  @Override
  public void run() {
    List<CompletableFuture<String>> jobs = workerJobs.stream().map(model ->
      CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new WorkerJob(openAiService,model),executorService)
    ).toList();

    List<String> taskResultModels = jobs
      .stream()
      .map(CompletableFuture::join)
      .toList();
    
    //Save result to DB
  }
}

And my WorkerThread like this:
public class WorkerJob implements Supplier<String> {

  private final OpenAiService openAiService;
  private final String model;

    public WorkerJob(OpenAiService openAiService,String model) {
        this.openAiService = openAiService;
        this.model = model;
    }

  @Override
  public String get() {
    try{
      return openAiService.generate(model);
    }catch(Exception e){
      return "Error";
    }
  }
}

The service looks like this:
The OpenAIClient is created globally so all Threads use the same Client but even when every thread creates its own client,i have the same problem.
The Client ist from here : https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/openai/azure-ai-openai/README.md
@Service
class OpenAiService{
  private final OpenAIClient openAIClient;

  @Autowired
  public OpenAiService(OpenAIClient openAIClient) {
    this.openAIClient = openAIClient;
  }
  public String generate(String model) {
    try {
      String content = null;
      List<ChatRequestMessage> chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
      chatMessages.add(new ChatRequestUserMessage(model));
      ChatCompletions chatCompletions = openAIClient.getChatCompletions("id", new ChatCompletionsOptions(chatMessages));
      for (ChatChoice choice : chatCompletions.getChoices()) {
        ChatResponseMessage message = choice.getMessage();
        content = message.getContent();
      }

      return content;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      return "Error";
    }
  }
}

I start the TaskThread also with an ExecutorService:
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2).submit(new TaskThread(List.of(""),openAiService));

Does the code presented actually manifest the behavior you describe?  Because I don't see anything in it that explains any appreciable delay at all.  Not even 10 seconds, much less 70.

No the long running Task is not included in this Code. Its a Rest Call to an other Service which took some time.

Details matter.  Requests for debugging assistance need to present a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  That doesn't have to be (and probably shouldn't be) one that makes calls to your REST API, because we can't test that, but you need to present some analog that is genuinely demonstrative of what the troublesome code is actually doing.

As a wild guess, though: the issue could be related to your use of virtual threads.  If you end up with all your virtual threads being supported by a much smaller number of carrier threads, and something about their workload prevents switching among them, then you could end up with them running serially.

If i use PlatformThreads instead of VirtualThreads i get the exact same result. Inside my WorkerJob i Call a Spring Service Bean which uses the OpenAIClient for my call to ChatGPt. I can update my code.

The point of a MRE such as I already requested is that we don't have to guess at the nature of the problem or the most appropriate solution.  The key to your issue is almost certainly in the code that you have withheld.  We're unlikely to be able to answer without that MRE.

Never pool virtual threads.

But when i use Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() for my virtual threads, how can i controll how many threads run in parallel ? Will this not slow down my application if i create for example 200 VirtualThreads and execute all with Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ?

You shouldn't control how many threads run in parallel.  You should let them all go.  No, it won't slow down your application.  That's the point.  Create a million threads if you want.

First of all, never pool virtual threads. Study JEP 444: Virtual Threads. To quote (my emphasis):

Virtual threads are cheap and plentiful, and thus should never be pooled: A new virtual thread should be created for every application task. Most virtual threads will thus be short-lived and have shallow call stacks, performing as little as a single HTTP client call or a single JDBC query. Platform threads, by contrast, are heavyweight and expensive, and thus often must be pooled. They tend to be long-lived, have deep call stacks, and be shared among many tasks.

The entire point of virtual threads is that they are so cheap in terms of memory and CPU as to be used like facial tissues: When needed, grab a fresh new one, use, and dispose.
Secondly, I suspect you can greatly reduce the complexity of your code.

CompletableFuture.supplyAsync

This kind of complicated async/reactive code is largely unneeded now with virtual threads. Just write your task in plain straightforward Java code, and submit to an executor service backed by virtual threads, one new virtual thread per task.
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;

Virtual threads are so inexpensive that you can reasonably run even millions of them simultaneously on conventional hardware. But of course cheap threads may run expensive tasks. If you need to constrain the overuse of precious resources (network ports, memory, database connections, etc.) by too many virtual threads, use a Semaphore with its pool of reusable permits.

how can i controll how many threads run in parallel ?

Use a Semaphore with a count of permits set to your desired maximum number of simultaneous tasks. But do so only if your tasks are expensive.

Will this not slow down my application if i create for example 200
VirtualThreads and execute all with
Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor ?

No, not at all, not if your tasks involve blocking.
You said you are making network calls. Network calls involve a huge amount of blocking, with long periods of time spent idle, waiting for a response. And your calls seem to be artificial intelligence LLM calls which likely mean even longer times spent waiting. Virtual threads allow for that time spent waiting to be used in running other tasks not currently blocked.
Two hundred network calls simultaneously running across virtual threads on even the cheapest low-end laptop is barely any load.
For tasks that are CPU-bound, such as video encoding/decoding, use platform threads rather than virtual threads.
Example of using Semaphore to limit execution of tasks
I cannot follow what you are doing in your async code. But I gather you want to make some web calls while throttling for no more than 200 at a time.
So here is an example app. Our task to be run on a background thread will pretend to make web calls by sleeping for ten seconds. We produce a thousand task instances, all assigned to run on virtual threads. We use a Semaphore to limit the number of simultaneously executing tasks to only two hundred.

So: 1,000 tasks taking 10 seconds each, with only 200 allowed at a a time, should result in an elapsed time of approximately ( 1,000 / 200 ) = 50 seconds.
Disable the semaphore.acquire( ); to see an elapsed time of only 10 seconds, as all one thousand tasks execute at virtually the same time, all waiting out their 10 second delay together (pretty much).

Using a Semaphore is simple. The pool of permits is reusable, calling acquire to grab a permit, and calling release to return the permit to the pool. The crucial part is using finally to always return the permit no matter the outcome of your code, even if an exception is thrown.
package work.basil.example.threading;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class LotsOfWebCalls
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        LotsOfWebCalls app = new LotsOfWebCalls( );
        app.demo( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        long start = System.nanoTime( );
        System.out.println( "Starting demo. Please wait. May take a minute." );

        // Sample data.
        final int countTasks = 1_000;
        Collection < UUID > uuids = IntStream.rangeClosed( 1 , countTasks ).mapToObj( ( int i ) -> UUID.randomUUID( ) ).toList( );

        // Create a new task for each of the UUIDs.
        final int limitOnSimultaneousTasks = 200;
        final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore( limitOnSimultaneousTasks );  // Pool of permits set to the maximum number of tasks we want executing simultaneously. 
        Collection < ProcessUuidTask > tasks = uuids.stream( ).map( ( UUID uuid ) -> new ProcessUuidTask( uuid , semaphore ) ).toList( );
        List < Future < WhatWhen > > futures = null;
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor( ) ;
        )
        {
            futures = executorService.invokeAll( tasks );
        } catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }

        // Process results
        Collection < String > results = new ArrayList <>( futures.size( ) );
        for ( Future < WhatWhen > future : futures )
        {
            if ( future.isCancelled( ) ) System.out.println( "Encountered cancelled task" );
            else if ( !future.isDone( ) ) System.out.println( "OOPS! This should not be possible. All tasks are done after the try-with-resources with executor service." );
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    WhatWhen whatWhen = future.get( );
                    String message = "UUID: " + whatWhen.uuid + " processed at: " + whatWhen.instant;
                    results.add( message );
                } catch ( InterruptedException | ExecutionException e )
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException( e );
                }
            }
        }
        Duration durationOfDemo = Duration.ofNanos( System.nanoTime( ) - start );
        // Dump results to console.
        System.out.println( "Demo elapsed time: " + durationOfDemo );
        results.forEach( System.out :: println );
    }

    static class ProcessUuidTask implements Callable < WhatWhen >
    {
        private final UUID uuid;
        private final Semaphore semaphore;

        public ProcessUuidTask ( final UUID uuid , final Semaphore semaphore )
        {
            this.uuid = uuid;
            this.semaphore = semaphore;
        }

        @Override
        public WhatWhen call ( ) throws Exception
        {
            try
            {
                semaphore.acquire( ); // Wait indefinitely until one of the limited number of permits becomes available.
                //Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds( ThreadLocalRandom.current( ).nextInt( 2 , 10 ) );
                Duration duration = Duration.ofSeconds( 10 );
                Thread.sleep( duration );  // Simulate doing work, such as making a web call.
                return new WhatWhen( uuid , Instant.now( ) );
            } finally
            {
                semaphore.release( );
            }
        }
    }

    record WhatWhen( UUID uuid , Instant instant ) { }
}

With the semaphore, demo takes 50 seconds:
Starting demo. Please wait. May take a minute.
Demo elapsed time: PT50.116122291S
UUID: 4012c419-ca8c-4c8b-b805-c582c67d6a5f processed at: 2024-04-25T20:38:05.443156Z
UUID: 6d997037-a065-49fa-97c1-e982108c5380 processed at: 2024-04-25T20:38:05.444954Z
UUID: 54cfdc66-82ca-47cd-bba3-84b2ae217e48 processed at: 2024-04-25T20:38:05.443691Z

Without the semaphore, demo takes 10 seconds:
Starting demo. Please wait. May take a minute.
Demo elapsed time: PT10.069915875S
UUID: db0287cc-dd9e-41c9-b064-294e38efcb01 processed at: 2024-04-25T20:35:39.545795Z
UUID: d5e79525-c2c0-4432-97e9-7071377a07e0 processed at: 2024-04-25T20:35:39.544811Z
UUID: d4d12f25-1dd4-46ba-ac6d-fff5ccec4bed processed at: 2024-04-25T20:35:39.544783Z
…

